# Fail2Ban SASL Filter Misses Failed Logins

Tags: regex, sasl, fail2ban

I am using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on my mail server.  I discovered this morning that there were some 5000 failed login attempts (in the course of 1 hour) via SMTP that didn't get picked up by my sasl filter.  Here is an example of an entry in /var/log/mail.log

```
Jan 25 04:39:56 ***** postfix/smtpd[23828]: warning: 114-32-231-17.HINET-IP.hinet.net[114.32.231.17]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

Here's my (unmodified) sasl filter definition for fail2ban:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Author: Yaroslav Halchenko
#
# $Revision: 728 $
#

[Definition]

# Option: failregex
# Notes.: regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile. The
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" can
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\w\-.^_]+)
# Values: TEXT
#
failregex = (?i): warning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2})?$

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

Can anyone recommend an improvement to the regex that would have also caught this record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define another failregex

```
(?i): warning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(:.*)$
```

I tested this regex with fail2ban-regex and is working.

Comment: +1 for pointing out fail2ban-regex tool, wasn't aware of that.  However...the difference in your regex is the last part and I don't see the issue there.   Did you test the original regex?  Using a quick test in python, re.match("(: [A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2})?", ": authentication failure") returns a Match object.

Comment: Yes I tested the original regex and I tried to give you the simplest solution :). They forgot to include "space" in [A-Za-z0-9+/]. it should be "(?i): warning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [A-Za-z0-9+/\ ]*)?$"